# is there a way to replace a string with seqencial numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

say a I have a var like

```js
var str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence'
```

can I replace it with

```js
var str = 'the 1 brown 2 fox 3 jumped 4 over 5 the 6 fence'
```

maybe `array.from` can help

Comment: Yes, you can. Use a regexp replacement with a callback function that increments the number that it returns as the replacement.

Comment: Or use `split()` to split the original string at `@` delimiters. Then use a loop to concatenate the incrementing number between each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Regex` approach:

using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with `i` which is gonna be incremented each time find character `@`:

```js
let str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence';
let i=0;
console.log(str.replace(/@/g, _ => ++i))
```

### `for-loop` approach

```js
let str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence';
let arr = str.split('@');//[ "the ", " brown ", " fox ", " jumped ", " over ", " the ", " fence" ]
let result = arr[0];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result += i + arr[i];
}
console.log(result)
```

### `reduce` approach:

```js
let str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence';
let arr = str.split('@');
console.log(arr
  .reduce((acc, curr, i) =>
    acc + (i !== 0 ? i : '') + curr, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback that keeps track of the count.

```js
let str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence';
let i = 0, res = str.replace(/@/g, () => ++i);
console.log(res);
```

Or, similarly with [`String#replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

```js
let str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence';
let i = 0, res = str.replaceAll('@', () => ++i);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure with a start value of one for the index.

```js
const
    str = 'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence',
    result = str.replace(/@/g, (i => _ => i++)(1));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: could you get accross the *cb* specially `(1)`

Comment: it calls the function with this value and returns a new function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
'the @ brown @ fox @ jumped @ over @ the @ fence'
.split('@')
.reduce((acc,cur,i,s)=> `${acc+cur}${(i+1)!==s.length?`$${i+1}`:''}`,'')
```

Comment: Good but you need to omit the `$` to expect the result you provide, and you could check my answer I solve it with many approaches, one of them is `reduce`

Comment: I use pg-node that's why I need it

Comment: Okay, and please don't let the question open, and accept the one that responds to you requirements!

Comment: Don't answer your own question unless it is truly THE answer. If so, then close the question as answered. If it's an attempt, include it in your question, while also providing context like the `pg-node` requirement